# Magetno 2 custom theme's css not deploying on production mode

Tags: magento2, css, developer-mode, static-content-deploy, custom-theme

I've set magento 2.2.2 on production mode.

I have a custom theme with a custom css main.css:

Now when I do changes to css file when magento in production mode it doesn't add straight away because it;s not symlink as developer mode.

then I   go ahead and do:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -t MYTHEME/default

php bin/magento cache:clean

and changes are not there.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the grunt or gulp instead of doing all the commands every time.
It works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to run below commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area=frontend
php bin/magento set:upg
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but I need send my theme language also if i run only php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy   it only send en_US I need en_GB  so I've run. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f --area=frontend    then php bin/magento set:upg
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

when I looad the frontend all the css is broken I have to refresh the page quite a few times to get the it kick in properly.

Comment: where have you define your main.css? can you please share with me your website url

Comment: I am on local dev server! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following works in production mode I've done numerous time and it seems to do the job well.

First:
Do the css changes then run in order

1- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

2- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US --area=adminhtml en_GB -f --area=frontend`

3- `php bin/magento cache:clean`

4- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

5- `Also clean once backend cache` too

Very important Clean browser cache! This is unfortunate because the user will not see the changes if their cache doesn't get clear.

UPDATE!  if the a user hits the url website for the first after `upg` command or while is running:

And before all of the other one happens then css and much more stuff as require.js will be cached and that is a disaster unless the user clean their browser cache it be ugly. hummm.

Thank you!